# creating new user for community this error showing

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

While i m creating new user for community this error showing, i have already enabled allow external user and self-registration.

**Error:-Your request cannot be processed at this time. The site administrator has been alerted.**

Any Solution for this?

Comment: you will need to get us full log and obviously need more input to help you with .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes a google search with the error message and context is your best friend.
Check this blog post. It should provide you with the necessary information to solve this problem.

http://carvingintheclouds.blogspot.com/2014/09/your-request-cannot-be-processed-at.html

Comment: i have gone through this blog and have done changes. but the thing is user is created but  he is  not able to logging. and when the user the registering the error is showing.

Comment: And your community is published?

Comment: Yes. and   i am receiving the email while having this error :-There was an error in registering a user in site Pasand_Hai. The error message is: portal user already exists for contact

Comment: This error seems to suggest that a portal user is already associated with the contact that you are using for the new user. Also the account for this contact, does it have an owner?